# Will column reordering following ColumnTransformer and OneHotEncoder affect model?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have used skikit-learn ColumnTransformer and OneHotEncoder to encode a dataframe containing categorical and continuous data (I did not use OneHotEncoder on the continuous data) but this has completely reordered the columns and removed the names.  Can I use this reordered array to develop a model or will I need to reorder them back to the original order so I can interpret the data later?

Answer (score 0):

If you are training a fresh model (no transfer learning), columns order should not be a problem.

Comment: Yes it is a fresh model to try and put into practice what I am learning on an online course.

Comment: Then columns order should not be a problem. Each attribute will receive a weight. But make sure that when predicting, you have the same columns, in same order.